# If I have a website, is it my responsibility what type of ads are shown?

Tags: halal-haram

If I have a website, is it my responsibility what type of ads are shown? For example, if an ad about gambling or alcohol is shown, would I get bad deeds. Thank you. I do not have any control over what is shown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, yes, it is.

Websites, including sites such as Facebook and YouTube, however, do not allow much control over the kind of adverts shown, but this is simply down to their business model. It's not impossible for them to allow a degree a control over them if they so wished. So a great deal of the responsibility here is down to them. And they are well known for shrugging off responsibilities such as these ... until they are pushed. Which to my mind is a very reactionary business model.

Comment: So I should avoid showing ads?

Comment: I said website, but I mean a YouTube channel which I do not have any control of what type of ads are shown.

Comment: I don't know if this matters but, I would not be making any income from the ads. YouTube is forcing people to put ads without any choice to change what type of ads are shown or removing ads.